# can i draw entity relationship diagram for a database of only one table

Tags: database-design

Please am working on my project on tracking system for employee. I have just the employee's id, longitude, latitude and other information on a single table in a database. I just want to ask if it is possible to draw an entity relationship diagram for the table. Thanks

Comment: which language.? do you create database

Comment: The answer is yes. How could it be no? Were you looking for something more? Please give a reference for your ER diagram style.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. It will be an unusual diagram because it will have only one entity: employee. Employee will have various attributes: ID, latitude, longitude etc., and the diagram will have no relationships. That's it! As simple as this:

[image]

Diagram available at https://app.quickdatabasediagrams.com/#/schema/c0f7vP6QekKYXjgtYaTElg (where I work for)